# Android add items to Listview.setAdapter which contains only specific items

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Is there any possible way to add items in listview using setAdapter which only contains specific items? for example I want to add in listview an items which contains a date of "Feb. 15, 2015" only.

Following the codes:

```
   final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(CalendarActivity.this, eventsList, R.layout.calendar_event_list, new String[]{TAG_PID,
                    TAG_EVENTTITLE,TAG_EVENTSTART,TAG_EVENTEND},
                    new int[]{R.id.pid, R.id.eventname, R.id.eventstart, R.id.eventend});
            ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

            SimpleDateFormat formatdate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM. dd, yyyy");
            String selecdate = formatdate.format(date);

            if (eventDates.contains(selecdate)) {
                    myList.setAdapter(adapter); //these line I want only to add items in listview which contains the value of 'selectdate'
            }
            else {
                myList.setAdapter(null);

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SimpleAdapter` is used for static data. Since you want to dynamically filter the data you should implement a custom adapter to do this. However, a cheap solution would be to filter the data before you setup the adapter. Like this:

```
ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
SimpleDateFormat formatdate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM. dd, yyyy");
String selecdate = formatdate.format(date);
// Filter selected events
List<Map<String, Object>> filteredEventsList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
for (Map<STring, Object> row : eventsList) {
    if (row should be shown) {
        filteredEventsList.add(row);
    }
}

final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(CalendarActivity.this, filteredEventsList, R.layout.calendar_event_list, new String[]{TAG_PID,
                TAG_EVENTTITLE,TAG_EVENTSTART,TAG_EVENTEND},
                new int[]{R.id.pid, R.id.eventname, R.id.eventstart, R.id.eventend});
myList.setAdapter(adapter);
```